# Why OSQuery does not include "Computer" event information when reading Windows EventLogs?

Tags: windows, event-log, osquery

I am trying to use OSQuery in an environment with WEF/WEC and what I am trying to do is to collect all the Windows Events that are stored via subscriptions in the WEC servers.

**My problem is that when I gather the windows events via OSQuery I do not seem to be able to get the field "Computer" which includes the hostname that actually generated the event.**

Did somebody manage to get this working? Or is it an actual limitation of OSquery? When looking at the windows_events table schema (https://osquery.io/schema/4.5.1/#windows_events) it does not seem that the "Computer" field has been taken in account.

As an example, I have a WEC configured in a host named DESKTOP-JC2OUUQ and I have a subscription there for a laptop named DESKTOP-BEH0A7O. The eventlogs are flowing correctly towards WEC an i can receive them. Following is one of the events I am receiving:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event" xml:lang="en-US">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" Guid="{E23B33B0-C8C9-472C-A5F9-F2BDFEA0F156}" EventSourceName="Software Protection Platform Service" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="16384">16384</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-22T16:20:17.2647971Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>907</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-BEH0A7O</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
<EventData>
  <Data>2020-12-18T12:30:17Z</Data> 
  <Data>RulesEngine</Data> 
  </EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Message>Successfully scheduled Software Protection service for re-start at 2020-12-18T12:30:17Z. Reason: RulesEngine.</Message> 
  <Level>Information</Level> 
  <Task /> 
  <Opcode /> 
  <Channel /> 
  <Provider>Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP</Provider> 
<Keywords>
  <Keyword>Classic</Keyword> 
  </Keywords>
  </RenderingInfo>
  </Event>
```

When I try to collect this event with OSQuery, i get the following output:

```
{
    "name": "windows_events_query",
    "hostIdentifier": "DESKTOP-JC2OUUQ",
    "calendarTime": "Thu Oct 22 16:26:14 2020 UTC",
    "unixTime": 1603383974,
    "epoch": 0,
    "counter": 0,
    "numerics": false,
    "decorations": {
        "host_uuid": "A7A0828C-1264-4E24-A67F-F5B69BE86165",
        "username": "vagrant"
    },
    "columns": {
        "data": "{\"EventData\":[\"2020-12-18T12:30:17Z\",\"RulesEngine\"]}",
        "datetime": "2020-10-22T16:20:17.2647971Z",
        "eventid": "16384",
        "keywords": "0x80000000000000",
        "level": "4",
        "provider_guid": "{E23B33B0-C8C9-472C-A5F9-F2BDFEA0F156}",
        "provider_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP",
        "source": "Application",
        "task": "0",
        "time": "1603383958"
    },
    "action": "added"
}
```

As you can see, among other fields I am not seeing the "Computer" tag which, to my knowledge is the only one containing the actual host who generated the event. **Is there any way to get that value with OSQuery or is it a limitation?**

Thanks!

Comment: How certain are you that it is the exact same event?  Is that the only Event ID 16384 in your log?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the same. In fact, this is just an example as it happens with every event im getting. I checked event viewer in both hosts to make sure there were no duplicate events happening in both servers.

Comment: Also, i have tried sending custom events via command line with the same results.

Comment: Ok, I was just noticing that there is a field `hostIdentifier` in the JSON which doesn't map to anything other than `<Computer>` in the XML.  There is also `decorations.host_uuid`, which may contain the information you need if you find out how to decode it (there must be a mapping table somewhere)

Comment: The hostIdentifier and decorations are added by the OSQuery on the top of the event. From what i know both make reference to the host running the OsQuery agent instead of the remote host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Osquery did not support the `Computer` field. It does now:

https://github.com/osquery/osquery/pull/6952